# apk fails on start after proguard

Tags: android, proguard

Im using the most recent Android Studio updated today.....and also using proguard 4.9 
My app runs perfectly from the studio to emulator.... but when i use proguard the app doesn't even start. I export the apk and separately install on phone or emulator, it still fails to start. I managed to get logging from the "proguarded" apk.
I use 2 external jars..... admob 6.4.1 and Google analytics V2, both are saved within the libs folder and referenced in the project set up. and run perfectly without proguard.
I appended this to my proguard.properties.txt

```
-libraryjars C:\Users\Paul\workspace\Xtreme Converter\libs\libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar
-libraryjars C:\Users\Paul\workspace\Xtreme Converter\libs\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar
```

but i get this logging

```
06-27 17:05:58.163    2194-2194/com.paul.xcon                  W/dalvikvm: threadid=1:           thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4ca6908)
06-27 17:05:58.163    2194-2194/com.paul.xcon                  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker
    at com.paul.xcon.ConvSel.onStart(Unknown Source)
```

ive tried very many variations of libjars even without the C:\ references still nothing,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok When i encountered the problem at first i thought adding

```
-libraryjars C:\Users\Paul\workspace\Xtreme Converter\libs\libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar
-libraryjars C:\Users\Paul\workspace\Xtreme Converter\libs\GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar
```

would solve it..... it didn't but i left it there,
I then updated my studio and also downloaded ad loaded the latest proguard into my SDK...
It would have worked but these things i added above prevented it i think.
Its now working fine after removing them.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this:

```
-keep class com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker
```

to your proguard config file.

But in real I didn't find a way to make it work with Android Dev Studio.

Comment: Your class path is probably incorrect. It should at least contain all library jars and, of course, your processed program jar